# Getting Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Entity could not be converted to string in DatabaseStatementBase->execute() error

Tags: php, drupal

Getting  website encountered an unexpected error, please try again while adding goals using goals module in demo framework drupal 7.
 and in recent logs I get the

**Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Entity could not be converted to string in DatabaseStatementBase->execute()** error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around.......
I disabled the personalize module and the error is gone. So the problem was some conflict between Personalize and goals module....... I 'm working on how to get these two modules working together

Answer (score 0):

Problem was----->
Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Answer: I have uninstalled XAMPP 3.2.3 control panel which was using php version 7.x
and then install XAMPP 3.2.1 control panel which uses php version 5.6.3. After using XAMPP 3.2.1 the problem is solved.

To see php version use the command as following

c:\cd xampp\php
c:\xampp\php>php -v